# rails refactor, block with conditional

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Have the following throwing an error:

```
<% @foo.each do |foo| unless @foo.nil? %>

<% end %>
```

Any way to get both the conditional and block on the same line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just stick a `to_a` in there:

```
<% @foo.to_a.each do |foo| %>

<% end %>
```

Calling `to_a` on `nil` gives you an empty array, calling `to_a` on an array gives you an array.

Answer (score 1):

IMO cleaner to make @foo be an empty list, which is what normally happens with Rails finders.

Or wrap up the loop in a partial, and just have the conditional in the mainline template.